# amazon redshift regex pattern match digits other than 0 & 9 like 1111111111

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to validate a field where values with repeating digits are not allowed. Like field should not have all these below cases

```
{'1111111111','2222222222','3333333333','4444444444','5555555555',
'6666666666','7777777777','8888888888'}
```

but 0000000000 and 9999999999 are ok.

I tried all the below patterns but I'm missing something small which I couldn't get through.

```
TRIM(field_nm) ~ '^\\d{10}$' AND TRIM(field_nm) !~ '^(0|9){10}$'
TRIM(field_nm) ~ '^\b\d{10}\b$'
TRIM(field_nm) ~ '^[1-8]{10}$'
TRIM(field_nm) ~ '^(?!0|9)(\1){10}'
```

But few are throwing error and few are matching when there is a digit repeating only twice or thrice like 9811115890.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try `regexp_instr(trim(field_nm), '^(?!(\\d)\\1+$)\\d{10}$', 1, 1, 0, 'p')`

Comment: Does `regexp_instr` help? The `~` can't be used with the regex above since you need the PCRE regex engine, and with `~`, you can only use POSIX regex.

Comment: thanks, leme try and update...

Comment: Yes, it worked but I used substr instead of instr...since I had to use it inside case when statement!

Comment: So what does it look like?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, sry held up in some personal work... Thanks for the suggestion. Since this actually provides integer as return i used regexp_substr. Like REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(field_nm), '^(?!(\\d)\\1+$)\\d{9}$', 1, 1, 'p') AS "chcek2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**regexp_substr** can be used for pattern matching with lookaheads and followed by. This can be performed by giving the option 'p' in one of the parameters.

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(TRIM(field_nm), '^(?!(\\d)\\1+$)\\d{10}$', 1, 1, 'p') AS "chcek2"
```

For more details, refer the [regexp_substr redhsift documentation guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html)